# Oracle DB - identifier too long

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created a connection in SQL Developer and added several tables to database. Also, I have defined some triggers. They all work well except for one that gives "identifier too long" error. I am aware of 30 character limit, but i can't see what causes this particular error. With this code, I'm trying to implement the Short-circuit keys.

**Tables:**
**Izvestaj** (*IzvestajID*, Datum, Opis, Tekst, PredmerID, NarucilacID, OsobaID, IzvrsilacID)
**Predmer** (*PredmerID*, Datum, Naziv, IzvrsilacID, LokacijaID)
**Izvrsilac** (*IzvrsilacID*, Naziv)
*Italic values* represent the primary keys of relations (tables).

**Triggers:**

```
create or replace TRIGGER "T_IZM_IZV"
AFTER UPDATE OF IZVRSILACID ON PREDMER
FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
BEGIN
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('ALTER TRIGGER'||'T_ZABRANA_IZM_IZV'||'DISABLE');
        UPDATE IZVESTAJ SET IZVRSILACID=:NEW.IZVRSILACID
        WHERE PREDMERID=:NEW.PREDMERID;
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('ALTER TRIGGER'||'T_ZABRANA_IZM_IZV'||'ENABLE');
END;
```

---

```
create or replace TRIGGER "T_ZABRANA_IZM_IZV"
BEFORE UPDATE OF IzvrsilacID ON Izvestaj
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Direct altering of IzvrsilacID is forbidden');
END;
```

I have added some rows to table "Predmer" (Izvrsilac and Izvestaj also have some values inserted) and when I try to change value of column "IzvrsilacID" (foreign key), i get an error:

```
UPDATE "KORISNIK"."PREDMER" SET IZVRSILACID = '1' WHERE ROWID = 'AAAFBRAABAAALDxAAB' AND ORA_ROWSCN = '675526'
ORA-00972: identifier is too long
ORA-06512: at "KORISNIK.T_IZM_IZV", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'KORISNIK.T_IZM_IZV'


One error saving changes to table "KORISNIK"."PREDMER":
Row 2: ORA-00972: identifier is too long
ORA-06512: at "KORISNIK.T_IZM_IZV", line 4
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'KORISNIK.T_IZM_IZV'
```

What could cause this error? I've tried several things, even renaming triggers, tables and columns to one-letter names, but without any success.
P.S. Sorry about naming. I didn't want to translate table and column names to English because it would differ their length, which seems to cause an error in the first place.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These lines:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('ALTER TRIGGER'||'T_ZABRANA_IZM_IZV'||'DISABLE');
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('ALTER TRIGGER'||'T_ZABRANA_IZM_IZV'||'ENABLE');
```

Should look like this:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('ALTER TRIGGER '||'T_ZABRANA_IZM_IZV'||' DISABLE');
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ('ALTER TRIGGER '||'T_ZABRANA_IZM_IZV'||' ENABLE');
```

Note the added spaces.

Without the spaces added, you were trying execute:

```
ALTER TRIGGERT_ZABRANA_IZM_IZVDISABLE
```

and

```
ALTER TRIGGERT_ZABRANA_IZM_IZVENABLE
```

which clearly isn't going to work.

Hope that helps.